# Implement an Modal with a ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xamarin, freshmvvm

I'm using freshmvvm.

**Modal**

```
public class Expense : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { get; set; }//here
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

I would like to give Images properties like (name, type, source)

```
 public ObservableCollection<ImageSource> Images { 
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
   public ImageSource source { get; set; }
 }
```

Comment: What is the question/problem?

Comment: What type of Syntax is it in your second code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I understand your problem. You want to add some "metadata" to the images. You could build a wrapper class around the ImageSource or derive a class from ImageSource (I'll show both):

**Wrapper class**

```
public class ImageWrapper
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
   public ImageSource source { get; set; }
}

public class Expense : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<ImageWrapper> Images { get; set; }//here
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

**Derived class**

```
public class MyImageSource : ImageSource
{
   public string name { get; set; }
   public string type { get; set; }
}

public class Expense : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<MyImageSource> Images { get; set; }//here
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In the second example, you won't need a property to hold the ImageSource, since the object itsel is an ImageSource with added properties. If that has no negative impact on your application, I would go with this. If that would need to much refactoring the first is example is also ok.